# CarrierWave and RMagick: Using process :resize_and_pad throwing up nil is not a symbol error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, carrierwave, rmagick

I've created an image uploader and have defined the following version within it

```
version :profile do
  process :resize_and_pad [100, 100]
end
```

When I upload a file, I get the following error message:

```
nil is not a symbol
```

Looking at the full stacktrace, it's coming from processing.rb

```
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:85:in `block in process!'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `each'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `process!'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:112:in `cache!'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:230:in `block in cache_versions!'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:216:in `each'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:216:in `cache_versions!'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:112:in `cache!'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:230:in `block in cache_versions!'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:216:in `each'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:216:in `cache_versions!'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:112:in `cache!'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:315:in `cache'
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:173:in `profile_image='
carrierwave (0.6.1) lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:37:in `profile_image='
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:212:in `block in update_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:211:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:24:in `update_profile'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of missing arguments, try

`process :resize_and_pad => [120, 120, "blue", "Center"]`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't use a simple string for the gravityType, try this:

```
process :resize_and_pad => [100, 100, "white", Magick::CenterGravity]
```

http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/src_over.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a hex code but you need the octothorp.

```
process :resize_and_pad => [1000,1000,"#222222", Magick::CenterGravity]
```